# Sum Experiment array / loop dilemma

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, if-statement

I am writing a program and I can't seem to make the IF action loop and check all of the arrays in the main.  My job is to figure out whether there exists any pair of numbers (i.e., any two elements) in this ascending sorted array that will add up to 20. All you need to do is to sum the values these two pointers point to and see if they are equal to 20, if so, output. otherwise, inspect the sum, if the sum is greater than 20,decrement the second pointer and if the sum is less than 20, increment the first pointer. cannot use the nested for loop approach!!  Not sure how to fix this... i've been at it for hours and have handwritten it with no luck.  thank you!!

```
// if val of arr at index i is smaller than at arr j, then return
    // smaller value
    // This function will inspect the input to find any pair of values that
    // add up to 20
    // if it find such a pair, it will return the *index* of the smallest
    // value
    // if it does not find such as pair, it will return -1; 

public class SumExperiment {

public static int check_sum(int[] array) {
int i = array[0];
int y = array.indexOf(array.length); // need value @ index of array.length to begin

//loop to repeat action

for (int arraysChecked = 0; arraysChecked < 5; arraysChecked++ )
{
    if ( i + y == 20)
        {
        return i;
    //  System.out.print(array[i]);
        }
            else if ( i + y > 20)
                {
                y--; //index @y
                }
            else if (i + y < 20)
                {
                i++; //index @x
                }

    if ( i + y != 20)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    arraysChecked++;
}
return -1;  //because must return int, but this isn't correct
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array1 = new int[] { 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16 };
    if (check_sum(array1) != 0)
        System.err.println("TEST1 FAILED");

    int[] array2 = new int[] { 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16 };
    if (check_sum(array2) != 1)
        System.err.println("TEST2 FAILED");

    int[] array3 = new int[] { 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15 };
    if (check_sum(array3) != 2)
        System.err.println("TEST3 FAILED");

    int[] array4 = new int[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16 };
    if (check_sum(array4) != -1)
        System.err.println("TEST4 FAILED");

    System.out.println("Done!!!");
}
}
```

Comment: `array.indexOf(array.length);` does not even compile! And hint: formatting and indenting matters. Your very unconventional style makes it 10 times harder to read your code as it could be.

Comment: Having looked 5 minutes at your code, me too - I give up. Most of your code simply does **not** make sense. My suggestion: fully step back. Throw away your checker method, and then, *first* solve that puzzle yourself. Figure how *you* would figure if *any* pair in that array adds up to 20. Then write your code again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused between the values in the array and the indices of the values. Here is a working version with variable names that make it easier to understand what's going on:

```
public static int check_sum(int[] array) {
  int leftIndex = 0;
  int rightIndex = array.length - 1;

  for (int arraysChecked = 0 ; arraysChecked < 5 ; arraysChecked++) {
    if (leftIndex == rightIndex) {
      return -1;
    }

    int smallerValue = array[leftIndex];
    int largerValue = array[rightIndex];
    int sum = smallerValue + largerValue;

    if (sum == 20) {
      // Returns INDEX of smaller value
      return leftIndex;
    } else if (sum > 20) {
      rightIndex--;
    } else if (sum < 20) {
      leftIndex++;
    }

    // NO NEED FOR THIS: arraysChecked++; (for loop does it for you)
  }
}
```